# Devise confirmation link keeps failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my production.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://example.com' }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```

The Confirmation mail which i get is

```
 http//example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=hzG8Tjsder8JjJ2D316U
```

The problem is obviously the missing the semi colon and I dont know how to solve this. I have tried the following:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'example.com'
```

Still getting the same link. How to solve this?

Comment: Could you post the code that is generating the confirmation link?

Answer (score 0):

`default_url_options` takes the same parameters as `url_for`. You should be able to specify `:protocol` in the hash.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => 'http', :host => 'example.com' }
```

For the `asset_host` you should be able to specify inline though:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```